# What is g1sense.int.godaddy.com?

Tags: spam, backlinks, referrer

I recently looked at my list of referrers (ie, previous page the user was on), and one odd one is a link like `http://g1sense.int.godaddy.com:15871/cgi-bin/blockOptions.cgi?ws-session=3372311093`.

The domain name just redirects back to `godaddy.com` though and going to the link doesn't seem to actually do anything. The odd thing is, I'm not the only one seeing this mystery referrer according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=g1sense++int+godaddy+com).

Because it seems so widespread, can anyone tell me what this is? Is my site being blocked by a user or in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing to worry about – it is actually a proxy filter from a piece of software called Websense. It is documented here on Websense software's official website:

http://www.websense.com/support/article/t-kbarticle/Websense-Web-Security-default-ports

I can only speculate that GoDaddy must employ the use of this software in their infrastructure. Either way, it is not really a problem from a webmaster's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing just happen and the visitor's IP resolved to Scottsdale, Arizona, USA; which is where the GoDaddy headquarters is.

Also, seeing the `.int` in the URL leads me to believe this is an internal system that GoDaddy employees use.

Further, I have been in contact with GoDaddy's domain disputes department regarding this domain name recently, which further leads me to believe that this system is some sort of online ticketing system.